# Variable store function as primitive type or reference type?

Tags: javascript

```
var f1 = function(){}

var f2 = f1;
```

It pointed to the same function as f1 or it store another copy from f1?

Comment: Why do you ask ? What practical problem is behind your question ?

Comment: I read about function expression vs declaration and then felt confused that it work as object or regular primitive type. so it work as pointer point to object?

Comment: Yes, you can see it as a kind of pointer, like for objects. In fact functions *are* objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `f2` is, like `f1`, a reference to the same function.

You can use the fact that functions are objects to prove it :

```
 var f1 = function(){}
 var f2 = f1; 
 f1.a = 3;
 console.log(f2.a); // logs 3
```

But as you can't change a function core, there is little practical use in knowing this, apart the fact you don't use much memory if you duplicate a function reference.

Comment: This is wrong either if you assign f1 with a number.   
`var f1 = 10;
var f2 = f1; 
f1.a = 3;
console.log(f2.a); // logs undefined`

Comment: @sza The problem you see with your test is because of autoboxing : you'd have a surprise if you'd log f1.a : you'll see undefined too.

Comment: @sza f1.a = 3 is destroyed before you call it

Comment: To be more precise : when you do `f1.a = 3`, you're doing `(new Number(f1)).a = 3` : you're changing a Number object that is immediately forgotten, not your primitive f1.

Answer (score 1):

It is really easy to prove using `===`

```
var f1 = function(){}
var f2 = f1; 

console.log(f2===f1)

>>true
```

So `f2` and `f1` are pointing to the exact same function.

Comment: Fun fact: `Number.NaN === Number.NaN // returns false`

Comment: This proves nothing. You have === equality for primitives types without them being implemented with references : numbers are copied for example.

Comment: @dystroy, I am not saying to use === to prove the numbers for sure. of course it makes no sense to compare the references between numbers since they are primitive types.

Comment: @dystroy Are you talking about the answer, or the first comment? Because the answer is fine, `===` (and `==`) will only return `true` when comparing two objects if the objects are the same. That's not clearly stated in the answer, but I believe it's implied.

Comment: @bfavaretto I mean the fact that values are here references to function is by design, like for all objects, but can't be proved just with ===.